# HTML content underneath WebGL animation not clickable

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to figure out why HTML content underneath a WebGL animation cannot be clicked or interact with.

Please see [example](http://samnorris.co.nz/kubo/index.html).

Currently the div containing the animation is set to:

```
.webgl-glitch {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

..otherwise it will not display at all.

I have tried setting a z-index: 1; property on the header/container div, but this does not seem to help.

Here is the HTML section of the header including the animation div:

```
<!-- Begin Header animation -->
<div class="webgl-glitch"></div>
<!-- End Header animation -->


<header id="principalheader" class="centerContainer aligncenter fullScreen tintBackground stonebackground" style="z-index:1">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Site logo-->
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img alt="KUBO" src="img/logo.png"></a>
            <!-- Site Principal slogan-->
            <h1>Digital Exploration for the the digital age</h1>
            <!-- Site Resume-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="hidden-xs col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <h2>CRAFT experiences that <strong>defy</strong> expectations<br/>
                        CREATE from the the twin <strong>virtues</strong> of inspiration and innovation<br/>
                        BEAUTY in simplicity and complexity <strong>combined</strong> for the best of both worlds</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <a class="fa fa-angle-down" href="#" data-scrollto="#about"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Another thing I have noticed is that if I wrap the .web-glitch animation div inside a HTML5 canvas element it also does not display at all? why would this be?

The only property I have on canvas in the the CSS at the moment is width: 100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because of the WebGL animation, it's because of the `.webgl-glitch` `<div>`. Putting one HTML element on top of another prevents one from clicking whatever is underneath it; it doesn't matter if it's transparent or not.

As for the `<canvas>`: anything you put inside a `<canvas>` element is supposed to be a placeholder for browsers that don't support said element; if your browser supports it, whatever is put inside the `<canvas>` will be simply ignored; so, if you have something like this:

```
<canvas>
    <h1>Sorry, but your browser does not support the canvas element.</h1>
</canvas>
```

On browsers that do not support canvas, the message "Sorry, but your browser does not support the canvas element." will be displayed to the user; on the other hand, browsers that do support the canvas will simply not display the elements inside the canvas tag, and will allow the canvas to operate normally.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... so do you know how I can have the .webgl-glitch div underneath the header container and still display properly? I have just tried putting it underneath but now the animation no longer displays...  (See: http://samnorris.co.nz/kubo2/index.html)

I'm not sure I quite understand your answer about the canvas element btw...

Comment: are you said that the canvas element is meant to be used only for browser fallback-specific code?

Comment: Hmm. nevermid... think I have got it. Have moved the .webgl-glitch to inside the header but just above the container... text is not selectable (not a huge deal I don't think?) but the arrow now appears to be clickable.

Comment: As for the canvas, it is not the fallback itself, the content inside it is the fallback; I have edited the answer and added an example.